# How do I create variable and accessing value from database?

Tags: c#, oledb, oledbdatareader

I have access database and oledb connection like this:

```
OleDbConnection Connection;
Connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=" +
               Server.MapPath("~/db.mdb"));
OleDbCommand Command;
Command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT FTPTARIHARALIGI FROM Table1 WHERE ID = 1", Connection);
Connection.Open();
OleDbDataReader reader = Command.ExecuteReader();
```

Select command returns just an int value, and I need to access this value to variable.

I tried:

```
int test = reader.GetInt32(0);
```

> Return: No data exists for the row/column.

But data exists and select command works.

How can I do this?

Comment: What is the type of `ID` column? And are you _really_ sure your `SELECT FTPTARIHARALIGI FROM Table1 WHERE ID = 1` returns data? What is the value of that returned value exactly? Is it a 32-bit signed integer? And if this returns one cell, try with `ExecuteScalar` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`OleDbDataReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) start out before the first row. If you don't call [`OleDbDataReader.Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.read.aspx) method, you never reach the first row.

From [`OleDbDataReader.Read` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);

> The default position of the OleDbDataReader is **before** the first
>   record. **Therefore, you must call Read to start accessing any data**.

And use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `OleDbConnection`, `OleDbCommand` and `OleDbDataReader`.

```
using(OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection(conString))
using(OleDbCommand Command = Connection.CreateCommand())
{
    Command.CommandText = "SELECT FTPTARIHARALIGI FROM Table1 WHERE ID = 1";
    using(OleDbDataReader reader = Command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if(reader.Read())
        {
            int test = reader.GetInt32(0);
        }  
    }
}
```

If you wanna get just one cell of your data, [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a better option. It returns the first column of the first row as an `object`.

```
using(OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection(conString))
using(OleDbCommand Command = Connection.CreateCommand())
{
    Command.CommandText = "SELECT FTPTARIHARALIGI FROM Table1 WHERE ID = 1";
    Connection.Open();
    int test = (int)Command.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a [reader.read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx) before your getint.

[EDIT] and as was pointed out in a comment, you're better off with ExecuteScalar if you're only after one value. And you'd also probably want a try- catch around your reader.GetInt32(0) to trap any possible errors...

E.g. to iterate over your results..

```
 if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                int test = reader.GetInt32(0);
// Do something else
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want only one single value you can use [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method

```
 command= new OleDbCommand("SELECT FTPTARIHARALIGI FROM Table1 WHERE ID = 1", Connection);
 command.Connection.Open();
 var value=command.ExecuteScalar();
 connection.Close();
```

now value variable has the value that you want